# Rename php.ini.default to the more recognizable and standardized php.ini

Tags: command-line, bash, rename, mv

When I type command:

```
mv /etc/php.ini.default /etc/php.ini
```

I get:

```
bash-3.2# mv /etc/php.ini.default /etc/php.ini
mv: /etc/php.ini.default: No such file or directory
```

Why cannot I rename php by command `mv`?

Comment: It's probably because `/etc/php.ini.default` doesn't exist?

Comment: It seems you’re following a guide. Please provide a link to it.

Answer (score 1):

What is the output of `ls /etc/`?

The message tells you, that there is no such file as `/etc/php.ini.default`.

`mv` can definitely do what you want, the problem seems to be something different.

Comment: Please take your time to rate answers or mark comments as useful if they helped.